# <button> inside a form

Tags: javascript, html

at the end of my web `<form>` there are two buttons - one is `<input type="submit">` and another is just `<button>`. the problem is that if I click `<button>`, it submits all the form. I wanted to assign some javascript function to that button instead of submitting, but since it auto-submits I can't do anything. How can I fix this?

Comment: `<button type=button>Submit</button>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Explain button type as `button` because by default it is `submit`

```
 <button type=button>Submit</button>
```

Comment: Didn't take into account the default type value for the button, that's why my form was being submitted by a button when I meant it to do another thing. +1

Answer (score 0):

Make the type as button and you can add onclick event to call javascript function.

```
 <button type="button" onclick='alert(1);'></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `onclick` must return `false` to denote it will not `Submit`, `true` will denote , it will `Submit` the form.
`<button name="button1" onclick="button1_clicked();return false;">Click Me</button>`